# Google Map Styles cannot finding Parking Lots

Tags: api, google-maps

I am using the Maps Javascript API and styling it.  The map loads fine with no errors and styles all the points of interests except for one.  I have not been able to find a way that styles parking lots(paid parking/underground parking/building parking/sports complex parking).

I've used just about every option that is listed in the reference table and am not able to featureType that will make it work. I also used the google map styler to create a custom map style but not one of the feature type options will change the parking lot style.

This is the code that I am using to style the map...

```
const styles = {
          default: [],
          hide: [
                {
                featureType: "all",
                elementType: "labels.text.fill",
                stylers: [
                    {
                        "saturation": 100
                    },
                    {
                        "color": "#999999" /* e944e9 */
                    },
                    {
                        "lightness": 15
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: "all",
                elementType: "labels.text.stroke",
                stylers: [
                    {
                        "visibility": "on"
                    },
                    {
                        "color": "#000000"
                    },
                    {
                        "lightness": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: "all",
                elementType: "labels.icon",
                stylers: [
                    {
                        "visibility": "off"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: "administrative",
                elementType: "geometry.fill",
                stylers: [
                    {
                        "color": "#260f50"
                    },
                    {
                        "lightness": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: "poi.park",
                elementType: "geometry.fill",
                stylers: [
                    {
                        "color": "#260f50"
                    },
                    {
                        "lightness": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: "poi.school",
                elementType: "geometry.fill",
                stylers: [
                    {
                        "color": "#260f50"
                    },
                    {
                        "lightness": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: "poi.medical",
                elementType: "geometry.fill",
                stylers: [
                    {
                        "color": "#260f50"
                    },
                    {
                        "lightness": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: "administrative",
                elementType: "geometry.stroke",
                stylers: [
                    {
                        "color": "#260f50"
                    },
                    {
                        "lightness": 10
                    },
                    {
                        "weight": 1.2
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: "administrative.neighborhood",
                elementType: "geometry.stroke",
                stylers: [
                    {
                        "color": "#260f50"
                    },
                    {
                        "lightness": 100
                    },
                    {
                        "weight": 1.2
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: "poi.sports_complex",
                elementType: "geometry",
                stylers: [
                    {
                        "color": "#260f50"
                    },
                    {
                        "lightness": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: "landscape",
                elementType: "geometry",
                stylers: [
                    {
                        "color": "#260f50"
                    },
                    {
                        "lightness": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: "road.arterial",
                elementType: "geometry.fill",
                stylers: [
                    {
                        "color": "#260f50"
                    },
                    {
                        "lightness": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: "road.arterial",
                elementType: "geometry.stroke",
                stylers: [
                    {
                        "color": "#260f50"
                    },
                    {
                        "lightness": 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            
            {
                featureType: "poi",
                elementType: "geometry",
                stylers: [
                    {
                        "color": "#220a4b"
                    },
                    {
                        "lightness": 21
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: "poi",
                elementType: "geometry.fill",
                stylers: [
                    {
                        "color": "#220a4b"
                    },
                    {
                        "lightness": 8
                    },
                    {
                        "weight": 1
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: "poi",
                elementType: "geometry.stroke",
                stylers: [
                    {
                        "color": "#220a4b"
                    },
                    {
                        "lightness": 8
                    },
                    {
                        "weight": 100
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: "road.highway",
                elementType: "geometry.fill",
                stylers: [
                    {
                        "color": "#220a4b"
                    },
                    {
                        "lightness": 8
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: "road.highway",
                elementType: "geometry.stroke",
                stylers: [
                    {
                        "color": "#220a4b"
                    },
                    {
                        "lightness": 8
                    },
                    {
                        "weight": 0.2
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: "road.arterial",
                elementType: "geometry",
                stylers: [
                    {
                        "color": "#220a4b"
                    },
                    {
                        "lightness": 8
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: "road.local",
                elementType: "geometry",
                stylers: [
                    {
                        "color": "#220a4b"
                    },
                    {
                        "lightness": 8
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: "transit",
                elementType: "geometry",
                stylers: [
                    {
                        "color": "#220a4b"
                    },
                    {
                        "lightness": 8
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                featureType: "water",
                elementType: "geometry",
                stylers: [
                    {
                        "color": "#220a4b"
                    },
                    {
                        "lightness": 1
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
              featureType: "poi.business",
              stylers: [{ "visibility": "off" }],
            },
            {
              featureType: "poi.government",
              elementType: "labels.icon",
              stylers: [{ "visibility": "off" }],
            },
            {
              featureType: "poi.medical",
              elementType: "labels.icon",
              stylers: [{ "visibility": "off" }],
            },
            {
              featureType: "poi.place_of_worship",
              stylers: [{ "visibility": "off" }],
             },
            {
              featureType: "poi.park",
              elementType: "labels.icon",
              stylers: [{ "visibility": "off" }],
            },
            {
              featureType: "transit.station.bus",
              elementType: "labels.icon",
              stylers: [{ "visibility": "on" }],
            },
            {
              featureType: "transit.line",
              elementType: "labels.icon",
              stylers: [{ "visibility": "off" }],
            },
          ],
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to target parking for styling (not everything can be targeted directly).  One option would be to query the places service for parking lots in the area and display those with your own custom icons ([example fiddle (with default marker icons)](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/q8kxzn3u/4/)) or create your own data for the parking areas you want to display.

Comment: This is a great idea.  I've went a head and created custom markers and labeled them as parking places.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to target parking for styling (not everything can be targeted directly).

You could try creating a [feature request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/support#issue-tracker).

Another option would be to query the places service for parking lots in the area and display those with your own custom icons or create your own data for the parking areas you want to display.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/q8kxzn3u/4/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
let map;
let infowindow;

function initMap() {
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  // Styles a map.
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: {
      lat: 32.7169289,
      lng: -117.1657514
    },
    zoom: 16,
    styles: [{
        featureType: "all",
        elementType: "labels.text.fill",
        stylers: [{
            "saturation": 100
          },
          {
            "color": "#999999" /* e944e9 */
          },
          {
            "lightness": 15
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        featureType: "all",
        elementType: "labels.text.stroke",
        stylers: [{
            "visibility": "on"
          },
          {
            "color": "#000000"
          },
          {
            "lightness": 0
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        featureType: "all",
        elementType: "labels.icon",
        stylers: [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      },
      {
        featureType: "administrative",
        elementType: "geometry.fill",
        stylers: [{
            "color": "#260f50"
          },
          {
            "lightness": 0
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        featureType: "poi.park",
        elementType: "geometry.fill",
        stylers: [{
            "color": "#260f50"
          },
          {
            "lightness": 0
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        featureType: "poi.school",
        elementType: "geometry.fill",
        stylers: [{
            "color": "#260f50"
          },
          {
            "lightness": 0
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        featureType: "poi.medical",
        elementType: "geometry.fill",
        stylers: [{
            "color": "#260f50"
          },
          {
            "lightness": 0
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        featureType: "administrative",
        elementType: "geometry.stroke",
        stylers: [{
            "color": "#260f50"
          },
          {
            "lightness": 10
          },
          {
            "weight": 1.2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        featureType: "administrative.neighborhood",
        elementType: "geometry.stroke",
        stylers: [{
            "color": "#260f50"
          },
          {
            "lightness": 100
          },
          {
            "weight": 1.2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        featureType: "poi.sports_complex",
        elementType: "geometry",
        stylers: [{
            "color": "#260f50"
          },
          {
            "lightness": 0
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        featureType: "landscape",
        elementType: "geometry",
        stylers: [{
            "color": "#260f50"
          },
          {
            "lightness": 0
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        featureType: "road.arterial",
        elementType: "geometry.fill",
        stylers: [{
            "color": "#260f50"
          },
          {
            "lightness": 0
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        featureType: "road.arterial",
        elementType: "geometry.stroke",
        stylers: [{
            "color": "#260f50"
          },
          {
            "lightness": 0
          }
        ]
      },

      {
        featureType: "poi",
        elementType: "geometry",
        stylers: [{
            "color": "#220a4b"
          },
          {
            "lightness": 21
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        featureType: "poi",
        elementType: "geometry.fill",
        stylers: [{
            "color": "#220a4b"
          },
          {
            "lightness": 8
          },
          {
            "weight": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        featureType: "poi",
        elementType: "geometry.stroke",
        stylers: [{
            "color": "#220a4b"
          },
          {
            "lightness": 8
          },
          {
            "weight": 100
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        featureType: "road.highway",
        elementType: "geometry.fill",
        stylers: [{
            "color": "#220a4b"
          },
          {
            "lightness": 8
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        featureType: "road.highway",
        elementType: "geometry.stroke",
        stylers: [{
            "color": "#220a4b"
          },
          {
            "lightness": 8
          },
          {
            "weight": 0.2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        featureType: "road.arterial",
        elementType: "geometry",
        stylers: [{
            "color": "#220a4b"
          },
          {
            "lightness": 8
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        featureType: "road.local",
        elementType: "geometry",
        stylers: [{
            "color": "#220a4b"
          },
          {
            "lightness": 8
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        featureType: "transit",
        elementType: "geometry",
        stylers: [{
            "color": "#220a4b"
          },
          {
            "lightness": 8
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        featureType: "water",
        elementType: "geometry",
        stylers: [{
            "color": "#220a4b"
          },
          {
            "lightness": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        featureType: "poi.business",
        stylers: [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }],
      },
      {
        featureType: "poi.government",
        elementType: "labels.icon",
        stylers: [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }],
      },
      {
        featureType: "poi.medical",
        elementType: "labels.icon",
        stylers: [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }],
      },
      {
        featureType: "poi.place_of_worship",
        stylers: [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }],
      },
      {
        featureType: "poi.park",
        elementType: "labels.icon",
        stylers: [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }],
      },
      {
        featureType: "transit.station.bus",
        elementType: "labels.icon",
        stylers: [{
          "visibility": "on"
        }],
      },
      {
        featureType: "transit.line",
        elementType: "labels.icon",
        stylers: [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }],
      },
    ],
  });

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  var request = {
    location: map.getCenter(),
    keyword: "parking",
    radius: '1000',
    type: ['parking']
  };

  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    console.log("results=" + results.length + " status=" + status)
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      console.log("[" + i + "] name=" + results[i].name + " location=" + results[i].geometry.location.toUrlValue(6));
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  if (!place.geometry || !place.geometry.location) return;

  const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map,
    position: place.geometry.location,
    title: place.name,
    label: "P"
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", () => {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name || "");
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
window.initMap = initMap;
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Styled Maps - Night Mode</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&v=weekly&libraries=places" defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```